# Firebase Cloud function listener stop after 1-2 hours

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```js
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require(__dirname+"/myserviceaccount.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://myproject.firebaseio.com"
});

db.ref('myref').on("child_changed", function(snapshot) {
   ...
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "listener",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^5.2.1"
  }
}
```

It works fine until 1-2 hour later and no error log. Anyone can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared doesn't start any Cloud Functions as far as I can see. I'm surprised that it deploys at all, but it definitely won't start a reliable listener in Cloud Functions for Firebase.

To write code that correctly functions in the Cloud Functions environment, be sure to follow the instructions here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started.

Specifically: the correct syntax to [set up code in Cloud Functions that is triggered by updates to a database path](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) is:

```
exports.listenToMyRef = functions.database.ref('/myref/{pushId}')
    .onUpdate(event => {
      // Log the current value that was written.
      console.log(event.data.val();
      return true; 
    });
```

Comment: is it normal behavior of cloud function right? I testing other function just using setInterval for write log every 1 hour but if long time inactivity about HttpTrigger this setInterval stop working.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas The maximum amount of time a function can run before it's forcibly terminated 540 seconds.